# Estou problemas para ler uma string dentro de uma função

Tags: c, string, struct

Boa noite, gostaria de saber métodos para ler uma string em C(Versão C99), já tentei bastante coisa, e não funciona, abaixo, o código defeituoso.

*Obs:* O erro que relato é que, logo após apertar "ENTER" no primeiro 'gets' da função cadastro, o programa buga, e exibe a mensagem "o programa.exe parou de funcionar".

*Obs.1:* Retirei os `< >` dos includes pois o navegador identifica isso como uma tag html e não exibe o conteúdo dos includes.

```
#include stdio.h
#include stdlib.h

int menu()
{
    int opc;
    printf("\n Opcoes: \n1. Cadastrar livros\n2. Consultar livros\n3. Alterar informacoes de livros\n4. Remover um livro da lista");
    scanf("%d", &opc);
    return(opc);
}
struct informacoes
{
    char nome[100];
    char autor[100];
    long long int isbn;
    char volume[10];
    int data;
    char editora[100];
    int paginas;
};
int cadastro(struct informacoes *livros, int i){
    printf("\nNome do livro: ");
    gets(livros[i].nome);
    printf("\nAutor: ");
    gets(livros[i].autor);
    printf("\n ISBN : ");
    scanf("%lli", livros[i].isbn);
    printf("\n Volume em romanos: ");
    gets(livros[i].volume);
    printf("\n Ano de lancamento: ");
    scanf("%d", livros[i].data);
    printf("\nEditora do livro: ");
    gets(livros[i].editora);
    printf("\nQuantidade de paginas no livro: ");
    scanf("%d", livros[i].paginas);
}
int main() 
{
    int opc = menu();
    struct informacoes livros[10];
    int i=0;
    switch(opc)
    {
        case 1:
            cadastro(livros, &i);
    }
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: quando eu mexi com C, tem uns 4 anos, ou utilizava gets ou scanf, se tentasse utilizar os dois, pau na certa kkkk

Comment: acho que não é esse o problema, kkk

Comment: Tente executar o programa com um [debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/sc65sadd.aspx) e veja o erro que retorna.

Comment: Aparece 1 warning e 1 note, anexo:

Comment: dnvisso.c:44:30: warning: passing argument 2 of 'cadastro' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
             cadastro(livros, &opc);

Comment: dnvisso.c:19:5: note: expected 'int' but argument is of type 'int *'
 int cadastro(struct informacoes *livros, int i){

Comment: O problema está nos seus parâmetros, ou seja, o `(struct informacoes *livros, int i)`, estou tentando descobrir o porque.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código na verdade tem vários erros, os 2 mais claros são:

1. Você não pode enviar um ponteiro para um método que você pede um valor inteiro como parâmetro:

Onde você colocou:

```
cadastro(livros, &i);
```

Troque por:

```
cadastro(livros, i); //Note que não possui o &
```

2. O método `cadastro` é do tipo `int` mais não retorna nenhum valor, coloque-o do tipo `void`, ou seja, não retorna nada:

Onde você colocou:

```
int cadastro(struct informacoes *livros, int i){
```

Troque por:

```
void cadastro(struct informacoes *livros, int i){
```

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado novamente, e desculpe pelos erros serem tão simples

Comment: Pelo que você está dizendo, parece ser o caso de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.

Answer (score 0):

faça dessa forma:

scanf("%[^\n]s",nome_variavel);

Comment: O problema persiste, tem como você ver para mim se o problema é na sintaxe?